# Python error exception

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I have a script which create  a temporary text file and delete after the user close the window.

The problem is that, the temporary text file may or may not be created depending on what the user does.Or sometimes the temporary text file may be deleted before the user exit. There are  three possible scenario.

1. The temporary text file is created with the name of 'tempfilename'.
2. The temporary text file is created with the name of 'tempfilename' but deleted before the user exit.So, when trying to remove the file it raise `OSError`
3. The temporary text file is not created and no variable called 'tempfilename' is created, so it raise `NameError`

I have tried using this code:

```
try:
    os.remove(str(tempfilename))
except OSError or NameError:
    pass
```

But it seems that it only catch the `OSError` only. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: Why are you catching `NameError`? You know that is only raised if you have a typo in your variable names, right?

Comment: @delnan: Read the question, which makes it sounds like `tempfilename` may not be created (presumably it is created in an `if` statement. I would have changed it to add `tempfilename = None` at the start and then do `if tempfilename:`, but it's not my code

Comment: @delnan i have the above code executed whenever user click on exit button. And the file name variable 'tempfilename' only created when user do specific task. And sometimes user close the script without doing anything so the variable name 'tempfilename' is not even created. It give me `NameError` in that case. I am a beginner so not sure if i am doing the right way though. But whatever works.. :D

Comment: @ChrisAung Always have the variable defined, initialized to some dummy value (e.g. `None`). Not only is this cleaner IMHO, it's also less code and you can stop catching `NameError` which might hide legitimate errors (e.g. typos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try:
    os.remove(str(tempfilename))
except (OSError, NameError):
    pass
```

Comment: Yes. :) And you are a big one.@Stephan

Answer (score 0):

```
tempfilename = None

# ...

if tempfilename is not None and os.path.exists(tempfilename):
    os.remove(tempfilename)
```

It's not good to catch `NameError` since it will hide other typos in your code (e.g., `os.remov(…)`).

Also, `OSError` does not always means that the file did not exist.  On Windows, if the file was in use, an exception would be raised (http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove).  In that case, you would want to see the exception so you could be aware of the issue and/or handle it another way.

Exception handlers should be kep as narrow as possible to avoid hiding unrelated errors or bugs